# How to split text into separate UITextView pages?

Tags: iphone, uitextview, sizewithfont

A subquestion is:

How do I determine what the built-in internal margins of a UITextview are?

I have a long master string of text that I am trying to split into separate UITextView pages that I can then scroll from page to page inside a UIScrollView.  I use the following method to determine what the height of a string in a UITextView is and whether the string is over the height limit:

```
-(NSNumber *)getHeightByWidth: (NSString *) myString
                   mySize: (UIFont *) mySize
                  myWidth: (NSNumber *) myWidth

{
int intMyWidth = [myWidth intValue];

CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(intMyWidth, CGFLOAT_MAX);
CGSize requiredSize = [myString sizeWithFont:mySize constrainedToSize:boundingSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];  
NSNumber *retNumber = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithFloat:requiredSize.height];
return retNumber;

[retNumber release];
}
```

I call the getHeightByWidth method using the following cellFont as the input for mySize:

```
UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:14.0];
```

The UITextView is 320 pixels wide, but I notice that the text doesn't go from the left edge to the right edge as there are internal margins which look to be around 10 pixels on each side.  So when I call getHeightByWidth I set myWidth = (320 - 10 - 10);  But after building strings to fit within the UITextView, there are usually gaps on the last row that could be filled with the next words in the master string.

Can anyone tell me why these gaps on the last row of the text occur using this process for UITextView?

Answer (score 0):

The built-in margins are represented by the property `contentInset`.

Also you can configure the margins yourself.

If you have your text view in IB, look for Content insets. The values must be 0, but it still displays some margin. Trying setting them to negative values such as -4 or -8.

In the code, do something like-

```
myTextView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-4,-8,0,0);
```

You have to set these values according to what you find suitable.

Comment: This doesn't answer the sub-question.  I want to know what the margins of the UITextView are already set at, not how to set the margins.

Comment: The answer is in my reply itself. The `contentInset` property gives you an `UIEdgeInsets` representing the margins. Edited my answer!

Comment: In IB the Content Inset values for the UITextView are set to 0.  But, I can see that the text is indented from the edge of the UITextView by about 10 pixels on each side.  So is there a way to determine what this 10 pixel inset value is?

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of this. But I guess if you can tweak this internal margin by hit & trial, then it should not matter.